# How to activate application launcher using meta key

Tags: kubuntu, kwin

I'm on Kubuntu 18.04 and was able to activate the application launcher using the meta key before, but it is not working anymore. How can I enable it again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turned out I had modified the file `~/.config/kwinrc` when I installed Latte dock and after I removed it, the meta key was no longer activating Plasma's application launcher.

To enable it again open `~/.config/kwinrc` and update the following section:

```
[ModifierOnlyShortcuts]
Meta=org.kde.plasmashell,/PlasmaShell,org.kde.PlasmaShell,activateLauncherMenu
```

Comment: Interesting! I don't have the `[ModifierOnlyShortcuts]` section in my `~/.config/kwinrc` (Kubuntu 18.04) and the meta key works to activate the launcher.

Comment: @DKBose That's strange. Are you using ksuperkey?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of ksuperkey. Anyway, things are working for you & for me :)

Comment: Just came across this and thought it may interest you: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/74673-Disable-the-Windows-Key-Popping-up-Launcher?p=422438&viewfull=1#post422438

Comment: Had the same problem as a result of installing Latte dock, then reverting back to the Plasma panel. This fix worked on Kubuntu 20.04. Thanks.

Comment: After fiddling with kwin-bismuth, my meta-key stopped working for some shortcuts, not for others. Adding the section to `kwinrc` fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

Though it might be late but I just faced with the same issue right after upgrading from 18.04 into 19.04. The solution is to right click on your application launcher and choose **Configure Application Launcher...**. Then in **Keyboard shortcuts** assign <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for it. You might get an alert for conflict with Plasma app shortcut for the same functionality, but just accept it and apply the change.

Now you should be able to use Meta/Super key to open Application Launcher.

Comment: That fixed it, finally. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This helped, on Ubuntu 22.10!

Answer (score 1):

> Mostafa Ahangarha's answer is correct and it works! I just want to
> clarify his answer:

Meta/Super/Windows key alone can not be selected as a hot key in Plasma. It has to have an "alias" of one or two other keys.

Once you have selected whatever one key (I used `Fn` -key) or two keys combination to open Launcher, Meta/Super key acts as alias for this/those two and you can open Launcher with Meta key alone.

It's explained here: [KDE Plasma Fixes - WindowsMeta key](https://zren.github.io/kde/#windowsmeta-key)

Comment: That link could one day be broken... just thinking.

Comment: I did also try to set Launcher as an applet to worktable, but I did not find a way to set META key activation there. It seems that the Launcher has to be in a panel in order this to work

Comment: @ThunderBird is right if I correctly understand what he is meaning: The Fn-key might not work permanently. For META-key the default alias key combination is ALT+F1 in KDE Plasma.