# Application Launcher on Win-Key = Meta-Key 2021

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, launcher

Back in 2013 the answer was ksuperkey for Plasma < 5.8
[How do I open the Application Launcher on KDE with just the meta ("Windows") key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246886/how-do-i-open-the-application-launcher-on-kde-with-just-the-meta-windows-key)

In 2018 there was something done to make it work out of the box, as long as an shortcut is assigned like Alt+F1
[How to activate application launcher using meta key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087909/how-to-activate-application-launcher-using-meta-key)

It used to work for me until Kubuntu 20.10, since 21.04 it is broken.

What is the 2021 way to fix it?

Comment: I restarted the system and ran xev to observe the press of the meta-key ... and guess what: now my app launcher opens and closes on a second subsequent press like expected.... gonna watch this for a little while and then, this might be closed.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on this. I'm also using 21.04 and the application launcher behavior of the Meta key sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. Messing with the keyboard shortcuts is not intuitive as there are multiple names for the same shortcut and the categories of how the shortcuts are nested are extremely confusing.

Ksuperkey is not available for download and the PPA has been archived. It states the fix is available in Plasma 5.8+.